# Error 404 bundle.js not found - Spring Data Rest and React.js

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I want to build the app with Spring and react, so I started learning from this tutorial: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/tree/master/basic

My project contains the same files - I did all step by step( just shared my project for help https://github.com/Lewan110/rest-react). 
Spring Data rest works well, because I getting right data, but when I go to http://localhost:8080 I got no data and an error with bundle.js

It's weird for me because bundle.js is generated in: \src\main\resources\static\built\bundle.js
also *webpack.config.js* looks good:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

[image]

I'm completely new in React(and JS) and I don't know where cause can be.

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle.js` file should be in `public` folder not in `src` folder (if you want to use `bundle.js` in development server, which of course makes no-sense).

When you build a react app for production use, it's ready to be used directly in a server of your choice .. So when you're in development phase, you don't build your react app until you finish up your work.

btw, the generated app shouldn't be in your `src` folder, it should be in the same folder where `public` and `src` folders reside.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have webpack installed, then and try running

```
npm run build
```